# max instances of selenium grid running at the same time with jruby & cucumber

Tags: selenium, jenkins, watir, watir-webdriver, selenium-grid

I'm trying to run my tests in parallel using a selenium grid.  I have my jenkins server, a PC which is just running the hub, and 3 PCs attached running nodes.  I can run 7 parallel tasks without issue, and rarely have an issue with 8, but as soon as I go to 10 or 12 I start getting issues.

Some of the issues i'm seeing are

```
Session [36531758-f9e2-40ed-95ea-9a811de7e5e1] was terminated due to CLIENT_STOPPED_SESSION (org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException)
```

AND

```
Connection refused - Connection refused
  org/jruby/ext/socket/RubyTCPSocket.java:126:in `initialize'
  org/jruby/RubyIO.java:1177:in `open'
  E:/jruby-1.7.16/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:762:in `connect'
  org/jruby/ext/timeout/Timeout.java:104:in `timeout'
  E:/jruby-1.7.16/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:762:in `connect'
  E:/jruby-1.7.16/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:755:in `do_start'
  E:/jruby-1.7.16/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:744:in `start'
  E:/jruby-1.7.16/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:743:in `start'
  E:/jruby-1.7.16/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:1292:in `request'
  E:/jruby-1.7.16/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:107:in `response_for'
```

and

```
Connection refused - Connection refused (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
  ./features/page_objects/my_project/my_page.rb:90:in `log_out_previous_user'
```

I know some companies like browserstack and other companies like that use selenium grid, so I know it's possible to run more than 8 instances at once.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you start your nodes, you specify how many of each browser can be used. That being said, the more browsers you have running at the same time on the same node, the more chance you have for one task to affect another (which I believe increases overall testing costs more than the parallelization saves). My take on best practice at this point is to skip using the grid entirely and set up one Jenkins executor per each node computer and have that as your instance limit.

Comment: The problem with the Jenkins executor solution is I have to pre-define the test beds, meaning it won't necessarily grow properly with our test bed.

Answer (score 0):

Grids are quite tricky as they are very dependent on the hardware that you are running in combination with test speed and command line parameters.

How are you starting the hub?  You might need to add "-maxSession x" where x is the number of sessions that your hardware can support (experiment to find this :-))

I'm not familiar with the error message, but it may be caused by the browser timeout setting on either the hub or the nodes.

To see all available settings, run this:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -h
```

Adjusting them based on your requirements is key to a stable grid.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation that we've been using at my work is a 5:1 ratio (5 nodes per 1 hub, and the hub itself counts as a node). This was decided before I joined the team, but it sounds like they fiddled with the number a bit, and 5 was the most stable.

Comment: we have 4 nodes connected, trying to run 3 per machine